# CoreData/SQL vs NSMutableDIctionary for fast retrieval of in memory tables

Tags: objective-c, performance, core-data, sqlite, nsmutabledictionary

I have a list where each entry has multiple "columns".

E.g.  List of queuedUpRequestsToDownloadData which can grow up to 500.  Each Request, has fields like, URLString to use, Content-Type of request, Priority, buffer requirements, has it started, how many retries have completed, taskID etc

It is possible I may have duplicate requests come in or new request that changes priority of one the existing request in the list.  So, I need to be able to do things like

1. Are there any requests in List with matching URL and if yes what is the priority?
2. Get the next priority X task that has not started?
3. Which is the task that corresponds to this task-ID?

Is there a speed benefit if I store the list as a SQL table/Core Data Entity instead of a NSMutableDictionary?

I will also try to create some tests to benchmark it, but if someone has some benchmarks handy that would help a lot.

Comment: No one else's benchmarks will apply to your specific situation.

Comment: Thanks @Avi.  So, what are the trade-offs, i.e in what areas are NSMUtableArray expected to be faster and what areas are using SQLite/CoreData expected to better?